# Is there a way to make a selection field multi selectable with checkboxes?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-12

in Odoo 12 I'm trying to make a series of fields visible by check box, however I want a separate selection for visible in form view and in kanban view.  Is there a way to make these checkbox selections and multi-selectable?

Python field declarations:

```
view_module_name_form = fields.Boolean(string='Module Name')
view_module_name_kanban = fields.Boolean(string='Module Name')
```

XML:

```
<label for="view_module_name_form" string="Module Name"/>
<div>
    <field name="view_module_name_form" class="oe_inline"/>
    <field name="view_module_name_kanban" class="oe_inline"/>
</div>
```

However I would like to have column headers as well (Form/Kanban) Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Better to create a new object and create a `Many2many` field and use `many2many_checkboxes` widget.

Ex: `<field name="my_m2m_field" widget="many2many_checkboxes"/>`

Comment: Thanks, I'm using separate booleans and a table for placement and spacing control.  And in this case I also have checks in place so that if someone only selects Kanban Form also gets selected since the field can only edited on the Form view.